# How to retrieve a file from http server

Tags: android, client-server

I have the following web server class found [here](http://turtlemeat.com). I need to write an Android application(**client**) which can retrieve a file from this server. It would be great if anyone would be able to help me to do it. Thank you.

**Server host address is: My-PC/ipaddress**

When I execute the client it gives an exception.

**java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect**

WebServer.Java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class WebServer extends Thread {

public WebServer() {

    this.start();
}

private void displayString(String string) { //an alias to avoid typing so much!
    System.out.println(string);
}   

private static final int UMBRA_PORT = 30480;
private static final int ROOM_THROTTLE = 200;   
private InetAddress hostAddress;

//this is a overridden method from the Thread class we extended from
public void run() {
    //we are now inside our own thread separated from the gui.
    ServerSocket serversocket = null;
    //To easily pick up lots of girls, change this to your name!!!
    displayString("The simple httpserver v. 0000000000\nCoded by Jon Berg" +
            "<jon.berg[on server]turtlemeat.com>\n\n");
    //Pay attention, this is where things starts to cook!
    try {
        //print/send message to the guiwindow
        displayString("Trying to bind to localhost on port " + Integer.toString(UMBRA_PORT) + "...");
        //make a ServerSocket and bind it to given port,
        //serversocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }
    catch (Exception e) { //catch any errors and print errors to gui
        displayString("\nFatal Error:" + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    // Attempt to get the host address
    try
    {
        hostAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not get the host address.");
        return;
    }
    // Announce the host address
    System.out.println("Server host address is: "+hostAddress);
    // Attempt to create server socket
    try
    {
        serversocket = new ServerSocket(UMBRA_PORT,0,hostAddress);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not open server socket.");
        return;
    }
    // Announce the socket creation
    System.out.println("Socket "+serversocket+" created.");



    displayString("OK!\n");
    //go in a infinite loop, wait for connections, process request, send response
    while (true) {
        displayString("\nReady, Waiting for requests...\n");        

        try {

            //this call waits/blocks until someone connects to the port we
            //are listening to
            Socket connectionsocket = serversocket.accept();
            //figure out what ipaddress the client commes from, just for show!
            InetAddress client = connectionsocket.getInetAddress();
            //and print it to gui
            displayString(client.getHostName() + " connected to server.\n");
            //Read the http request from the client from the socket interface
            //into a buffer.
            BufferedReader input =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionsocket.
                            getInputStream()));
            //Prepare a outputstream from us to the client,
            //this will be used sending back our response
            //(header + requested file) to the client.
            DataOutputStream output =
                    new DataOutputStream(connectionsocket.getOutputStream());

            //as the name suggest this method handles the http request, see further down.
            //abstraction rules
            http_handler(input, output);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { //catch any errors, and print them
            displayString("\nError:" + e.getMessage());
        }

    } //go back in loop, wait for next request
}

//our implementation of the hypertext transfer protocol
//its very basic and stripped down
private void http_handler(BufferedReader input, DataOutputStream output) {
    int method = 0; //1 get, 2 head, 0 not supported
    String http = new String(); //a bunch of strings to hold
    String path = new String(); //the various things, what http v, what path,
    String file = new String(); //what file
    String user_agent = new String(); //what user_agent
    try {
        //This is the two types of request we can handle
        //GET /index.html HTTP/1.0
        //HEAD /index.html HTTP/1.0
        String tmp = input.readLine(); //read from the stream
        String tmp2 = new String(tmp);
        tmp.toUpperCase(); //convert it to uppercase
        if (tmp.startsWith("GET")) { //compare it is it GET
            method = 1;
        } //if we set it to method 1
        if (tmp.startsWith("HEAD")) { //same here is it HEAD
            method = 2;
        } //set method to 2

        if (method == 0) { // not supported
            try {
                output.writeBytes(construct_http_header(501, 0));
                output.close();
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception e3) { //if some error happened catch it
                displayString("error:" + e3.getMessage());
            } //and display error
        }
        //}

        //tmp contains "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0 ......."
        //find first space
        //find next space
        //copy whats between minus slash, then you get "index.html"
        //it's a bit of dirty code, but bear with me...
        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < tmp2.length(); a++) {
            if (tmp2.charAt(a) == ' ' && start != 0) {
                end = a;
                break;
            }
            if (tmp2.charAt(a) == ' ' && start == 0) {
                start = a;
            }
        }
        path = tmp2.substring(start + 2, end); //fill in the path
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        displayString("errorr" + e.getMessage());
    } //catch any exception

    //path do now have the filename to what to the file it wants to open
    displayString("\nClient requested:" + new File(path).getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
    FileInputStream requestedfile = null;

    try {

        //try to open the file,
        requestedfile = new FileInputStream(path);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            //if you could not open the file send a 404
            output.writeBytes(construct_http_header(404, 0));
            //close the stream
            output.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e2) {}
        displayString("error" + e.getMessage());
    } //print error to gui

    //happy day scenario
    try {
        int type_is = 0;
        //find out what the filename ends with,
        //so you can construct a the right content type
        if (path.endsWith(".zip") ) {
            type_is = 3;
        }
        if (path.endsWith(".jpg") || path.endsWith(".jpeg")) {
            type_is = 1;
        }
        if (path.endsWith(".gif")) {
            type_is = 2;      
        }
        if (path.endsWith(".ico")) {
            type_is = 4;
        }
        if (path.endsWith(".xml")) {
            type_is = 5;
        }
        //write out the header, 200 ->everything is ok we are all happy.
        output.writeBytes(construct_http_header(200, 5));

        //if it was a HEAD request, we don't print any BODY
        if (method == 1) { //1 is GET 2 is head and skips the body
            byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                //read the file from filestream, and print out through the
                //client-outputstream on a byte per byte base.
                int b = requestedfile.read(buffer, 0,1024);
                if (b == -1) {
                    break; //end of file
                }
                output.write(buffer,0,b);
            }
            //clean up the files, close open handles

        }
        output.close();
        requestedfile.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e) {}

}

//this method makes the HTTP header for the response
//the headers job is to tell the browser the result of the request
//among if it was successful or not.
private String construct_http_header(int return_code, int file_type) {
    String s = "HTTP/1.0 ";
    //you probably have seen these if you have been surfing the web a while
    switch (return_code) {
    case 200:
        s = s + "200 OK";
        break;
    case 400:
        s = s + "400 Bad Request";
        break;
    case 403:
        s = s + "403 Forbidden";
        break;
    case 404:
        s = s + "404 Not Found";
        break;
    case 500:
        s = s + "500 Internal Server Error";
        break;
    case 501:
        s = s + "501 Not Implemented";
        break;
    }

    s = s + "\r\n"; //other header fields,
    s = s + "Connection: close\r\n"; //we can't handle persistent connections
    s = s + "Server: SimpleHTTPtutorial v0\r\n"; //server name

    switch (file_type) {
    //plenty of types for you to fill in
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        s = s + "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n";
        break;
    case 2:
        s = s + "Content-Type: image/gif\r\n";
        break;
    case 3:
        s = s + "Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed\r\n";
        break;
    case 4:
        s = s + "Content-Type: image/x-icon\r\n";
    case 5:
        s = s + "Content-Type: text/xml\r\n";
        break;
    default:
        s = s + "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
        break;
    }

    ////so on and so on......
    s = s + "\r\n"; //this marks the end of the httpheader
    //and the start of the body
    //ok return our newly created header!
    return s;
}

}
```

Client.Java

```
public class WatchMeManagerClient {

private static Socket socket;
private static PrintWriter printWriter;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        URL url;
        URLConnection urlConn;
        DataInputStream dis;

        url = new URL("http://ipaddress/xml/userGroup.xml");

        urlConn = url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setDoInput(true);
        urlConn.setUseCaches(false);

        dis = new DataInputStream(urlConn.getInputStream());
        String s;

        while ((s = dis.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        dis.close();
    }

    catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        System.out.println(mue.toString());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe.toString());
    }
}
}
```

When I run the code on PC it works. But when I try to execute it on the Android Device it gives following errors.

Comment: Are you connecting to the right port? The server is listening on port 30480, so you should connect to http://ipaddress:30480/xml/userGroup.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such problems are either due to one of the following:

1. The port is wrong
2. Firewall is stopping it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Sockets require the following permission which I think you are missing:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you allow internet access in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```