# Gather a list of my apps

Tags: android

Say I have 10+ apps now and the list of my apps keep growing, I want every of my apps having a list to link to all of the apps made by me. It is not good to hard code all the URLs within every app because this breaks scalability. A better approach is to have to each app connect to some web service and when the list is updated, the delta of the list is downloaded.

Are there any APIs or services already doing this kind of thing?

I ask because I have no experience in web programming, implementing this would takes weeks or even months.

Comment: Just place a file with JSON or XML content on the internet. You may even place it in a dropbox public folder (check their TOS first). Just load that file on start, and there's your list. Beware that most power users stay away from ad-ware, and if I downloaded an app which advertises all the other (possibly unrelated) apps by the same developer, I'd remove it pretty quickly.

Comment: it's pretty simple. host a file on your website and at startup have the app download the list - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597595/how-to-retrieve-a-file-from-http-server - if it's only ten apps you don't need to worry about diff etc

Comment: Thank you, I think that is the easiest way to do that.